# Get a list of map keys from a deque in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, java-stream, deque

I have a deque

```
Deque<Map<int, String> cars = new LinkedList();
```

I want to use Java stream to collect all the keys from the deque map into a

```
List<int>.
```

Is there any way to do this?

I tried something like

```
cars.stream().map(car -> car.keySet()).collect(Collectors.toList()
```

This question is different from the previous question. I want to collect all the keys, as opposed to removing a map from the deque.

Comment: you probably meant `Map<Integer, String>`, `List<Integer>` and `LinkedList<>()`. Because primitives are not valid generic parameters and raw types should not be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap()`:

```
cars.stream()
    .map(Map::keySet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: works great. If I want to convert the List<int> to a List<String> within the same stream, is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just add a `.map(String::valueOf)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `flatMap` the maps' keys:

```
List<Integer> keys =
    cars.stream().flatMap(car -> car.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```